# AJAX search in grails

Tags: ajax, grails, grails-3.0.9

Is there any plugin that supports AJAX search in `Grails` 3.x? It should load search results in the current page instead of open a new page/view.

Comment: Ajaxdependancyselection I think will be of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally done it completely in JavaScript. It may be possible with the plugin `Ajaxdependancyselection` mentioned by @vahid but for me it was a lot easier to just do this with `JQuery`.